# How can I use OpenGL 4 features through WebGL

Tags: webgl, opengl-4

I want to use some of the features of OpenGL 4 (specifically, tessellation shaders and newer shader language versions) from WebGL. Is this possible, in either a standards-compliant or a hackish way? Is there some magic value I could use instead of, say, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER to tell the underlying GL implementation to compile tessellation shaders?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebGL is based on the OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification so you wouldn't be able to use GL4 unless the browser also somehow exposes a GL4 interface to JavaScript which i doubt. Even if a browser would give you such an interface it would only work on that browser.